# Prove for a semigroup $S$ that $SeS = SfS$ is equivalent to the existence of $x, y \in S$ such that $xy = e$ and $yx = f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

Let $S$ be a *finite* semigroup and let $e, f$ be idempotents of $S$. I want to show that $SeS = SfS$ is equivalent to the existence of $x, y \in S$ such that $xy = e$ and $yx = f$.

The second direction is pretty straightforward since $SeeS = SxyxyS \subset SyxS = SfS$. The other direction I know is true, it can be found in lists of equivalent statements in some textbooks, but I'm hoping for there to be a very nice direct proof.

Comment: Did you switch from $x,y$ to $a,b$ between the first paragraph and the second?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes! Sorry it's fixed now

Comment: @Milten Also yes, it's supposed to be a 2-sided ideal.

Comment: @user86420 Can you give an example where this happens? That might help a lot in coming up with an answer. I thought about looking at $S = (\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z, \cdot)$, but I couldn't find any idempotents with $eS = fS$ (and I think it's impossible considering CRT).

Comment: @Milten $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is indeed impossible. But the inverse symmetric group $IS_n$ where $e, f$ are idempotents of the same rank is a nice example where it holds.

Comment: Okay, so the case of symmetric inverse semigroup is rather well-behaved (for one thing it's inverse). The idempotents are partial identity functions $1_X$, and $S1_XS = S1_YS$ iff $|X|=|Y|$. From this we must have $1_X=\sigma1_Y\sigma^{-1}$ and $1_Y=\sigma^{-1}1_X\sigma$ for some $\sigma$. More generally, if $1_X=\sigma1_Y\tau$, then in fact $1_Y = \tau1_X\sigma$, and also $1_X\sigma\tau=1_X$ and $1_Y\tau\sigma=1_Y$. I wonder if some of these ideas can be extended to the general case. If we can find e.g. $x,y$ s.t. $e=xfy$ and $f=yex$, we would be golden.

Comment: In any case, aren’t there proofs in those textbooks you mention?

Comment: @Milten Yes, but I haven't been able to make use of it. We have $SeS = SfS \implies Se \cong Sf$ by showing that if $f = t e s$ we have a bijection $\phi(e) = esf$ (since a fcn from Se is defined by its value at e) by a cardinality argument. But I don't see how we can then explicitly find out what $\phi^{-1}(f)$ is

Comment: "it can be found in lists of equivalent statements in some textbooks". Could you give one reference of a textbook where this result is stated? I have some serious doubts.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Sorry! Very stupid of me not to give it right away. Theorem 1.11 in Steinberg's Rep theory of monoids covers it.

Comment: Sorry to say, but the theorem you refer to assumes that the semigroup is finite, as clearly stated by Steinberg at the beginning of the section.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Oh I didn't realize that was the case, thank you. Is that assumption required? You said you had serious doubts, did you have a counterexample in mind?

Comment: I will also update the question to finite semigroups.

Comment: The theorem I know states that two idempotents are conjugate if and only if they are $\cal D$-equivalent, and this resul holds for any semigroup (finite or not). Here you use $\cal J$ instead of $\cal D$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem**. Two idempotents of a semigroup are conjugate if and only if they are $\cal D$-equivalent.

This result is proved for instance in [1, Proposition 2.3.5]. The proof relies on Green's Lemma, that I will not recall here. Let $R(x)$, $L(x)$ and $H(x)$ denote the $\cal R$-class, the $\cal L$-class and the $\cal H$-class of an element $x$, respectively.

**Proof**.
Suppose that $e = uv$ and $f = vu$ for some $u, v \in
S$. Then $uvuv = uv$ and $vuvu = vu$, whence $uv \mathop{\cal R} uvu$ and $uvu
\mathop{\cal L} vu$. Thus $e = uv \mathop{\cal D} vu = f$.

Suppose now that $e \mathop{\cal D} f$. Then there exists $s \in S$ such
that $e \mathop{\cal R} s$ and $s \mathop{\cal L} f$. By Green's lemma, there exists an element $\bar s \in L(e) \cap R(f)$ such that $\bar ss = f$. Thus
$s\bar ss = sf = s$ and $\bar ss\bar s = f\bar s = \bar s$.
It follows that $\bar s$ is an inverse of $s$. Thus $s\bar s$ is an idempotent of $H(e)$ and thus is equal to $e$.

Your question considers the condition $SeS = SfS$, which means that $e \mathop{\cal J} f$. It is a well-known fact that ${\cal J} = {\cal D}$ in a finite semigroup. This property also holds if, for every $\cal J$-class $J$ of $S$, the set of $\cal L$-classes (respectively $\cal R$-classes) contained in $J$ contains a minimal member. In particular, it holds in any periodic semigroup. It also holds in compact topological semigroups.

[1] J.~M. Howie, *Fundamentals of semigroup theory*, London
Mathematical Society Monographs. New Series vol.~12, The Clarendon Press
Oxford University Press, New York, 1995.

Comment: $\mathcal D\subseteq \mathcal J$ is always true. The converse for finite semigroups can be found in (among many others, I'm sure) Grillet's Introduction off the top of my head.

Comment: Yes, it is proved in every reasonable book on semigroups.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thank you for coming back and closing the question with such a nice answer! I know now that this only works in general for $\mathcal{D}$-equivalent idempotents, but I haven't been able to think out a counterexample for $\mathcal{J}$-equivalent idempotents in some infinite semigroup. Is there one in Howie's fundamentals?

Comment: You're welcome. Well, I know of semigroups in which ${\cal D} \not= {\cal J}$ and I am confident there should be examples of $\cal J$-equivalent idempotents that are not conjugate. However, I don't have a counterexample that comes to my mind and, to tell the truth, I lack the motivation to prove such a negative result. Sorry.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin No worries! But could you tell me some examples of semigroups $\mathcal{D} \neq \mathcal{J}$ so I can investigate them for $\mathcal{J}$-equivalent idempotents?